# How to make my app icon bounce in the Mac dock

Tags: java, macos

Well I'm writing an IRC client in Java and I was wondering if there was a way to make my app's icon bounce in the dock when a nickalert is triggered (or any other relevant notification).

If Windows also has some sort of notification system I'd like to know about it as well.

Comment: Windows 7 has a notification system by which the task icon can flash, but neither are available through pure Java, you'll need a JNI/JNA solution

Comment: Under the Mac OS, try using [Application#requestUserAttention](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/Application.html#requestUserAttention%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the MacOS, try using something like [Application#requestUserAttention(boolean)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/Application.html#requestUserAttention%28boolean%29)

```
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
...
Application application = Application.getApplication();
application.requestUserAttention(false);
```

nb- I've not tried this my self - sorry.

**Updated with example**

From the [JavaDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/Application.html#requestUserAttention%28boolean%29)

> Requests user attention to this application (usually through bouncing
>   the Dock icon). Critical requests will continue to bounce the Dock
>   icon until the app is activated. An already active application
>   requesting attention does nothing.

That means, that if the application has focus, then the method will do nothing.

Test on Mac OSX 10.7.5, Java 1.7.0_07

```
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestMacIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMacIcon();
    }

    public TestMacIcon() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            final Application application = Application.getApplication();
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("clicked");
                        application.requestUserAttention(true);
                        application.setDockIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Java.png")));
                        application.setDockIconBadge("Blah");
                        application.requestUserAttention(true);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Timer time = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (!SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TestPane.this).hasFocus()) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        System.out.println("Pay attention!!");
                        application.requestUserAttention(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            time.setRepeats(true);
            time.setCoalesce(true);
            time.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Ps make sure that you do-focus application ;)

Comment: As promising as it looked, it doesn't appear to work...
I will use this class though for other things so thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does. If you read the JavaDocs, it says that if the application has focus, this method does nothing.  Try the example I've included, but make sure you click something else ;)

Comment: Well I tried it without focus but it didn't work... I'll give your example a shot.

Comment: Ok I managed to implement it (properly) and it works!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i am not able to make the icon bounce for swt application it works fine for pure java applications pfa https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321949