# How to make my e4 swt app icon bounce in the Mac dock

Tags: java, macos, swt, e4

i am trying to make my mac tray icon as suggested in [How to make my app icon bounce in the Mac dock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079783/how-to-make-my-app-icon-bounce-in-the-mac-dock)

this works fine with pure java applications and swings

but this doesn't works with e4 swt applications , how to make it bounce in this type applications

ref:
pfa of the sample code in the following link
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.requestUserAttention` works for me in an e4 application (Eclipse 4.3.2 on Mac 10.9.3 with Java 1.8 update 5).

Note: It only does something if the application is not the focused app. With the `false` parameter there is only one bounce, specify `true` to make it bounce until the app has focus.

Update:

You can also do this using the SWT Mac specific classes, like this:

```
private static final long sel_requestUserAttention_ = OS.sel_registerName("requestUserAttention:");

private static final int NSCriticalRequest = 0;
private static final int NSInformationalRequest = 10;

...

NSApplication app = NSApplication.sharedApplication();

OS.objc_msgSend(app.id, sel_requestUserAttention_, NSInformationalRequest);
```

Use `NSInformationalRequest` for a single bounce, `NSCriticalRequest` to bounce until the app receive focus.

Since this is Mac only SWT code you will have to put it in a plugin or fragment with a platform filter in the `MANIFEST.MF` such as:

```
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.ws=cocoa) (osgi.os=macosx) (osgi.arch=x86_64) )
```

Update:

The above code is for 64 bit SWT on Mac OSX, for 32 bit SWT use

```
private static final int sel_requestUserAttention_ = OS.sel_registerName("requestUserAttention:");
```

Comment: for me in e4 applications Application.requestUserAttention not working i have created an test code , can you go through the example [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321949) .

Comment: i am getting the following error 2014-06-18 13:01:25.048 java[678:d07] -[SWTApplication (null selector)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175f40
2014-06-18 13:01:25.049 java[678:d07] *** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0x0) for message '<null selector>' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime (0x18ec5e0)-- abort

Comment: What version of Mac OSX are you using?

Comment: platform-> 
mac :os x 10.9.02
swt : v 3.102.1
java : 1.6 (default apples version)

Comment: public class TestClass {
protected Shell shell;
public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
TestClass window = new TestClass();
window.open();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void open() {
Display display = Display.getDefault();
createContents();
shell.open();
shell.layout();
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new  Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
com.apple.eawt.Application application=Application.getApplication();
application.requestUserAttention(true);
});
}
protected void createContents() {
shell = new Shell();
shell.setSize(450, 300);
}
}
this don't work

Comment: please check this [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321949) for attachment

Comment: requestUserAttention only does something when the app is **not** the active app. So running a test program that calls it immediately will not do anything.

Comment: i have put the requestUserAttention in a wile loop 
while(true){
requestUserAttention(true);
}
and the application is not active 
not worked for me when "the application is inactive or not focused "

code doesn't work for e4 example 
but works fine with pure java application